# Error in printing AST ANTLR C# grammar: The command ""C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" …" exited with code 3

Tags: c#, antlr

I added `output=AST;` to the grammar options at the top of cs.g to print out the tree.

```
options
{language = 'CSharp2';
output=AST;
}
```

When I build up the project after the change I got this message:

> The command ""C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\antlr-3.3.jar" org.antlr.Tool -message-format vs2005 cs.g  -make  -Xconversiontimeout 2500 -Xmultithreaded" exited with code 3. C:\Users\AMD\Desktop\Complier\antlrcsharp100620\UnitTest\UnitTest.csproj 68 24 UnitTest

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the following lines in UnitTest.csproj:

```
<JavaDir>C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java</JavaDir>
<JarDir>C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib</JarDir>
```

to

```
<JavaDir>path to java.exe</JavaDir>
<JarDir>C:\users\amd\desktop\compiler\antlrcsharp100620\browse\browse\Antlr.Runtime\CSharp2</JarDir>
```

The JavaDir path needs point to the location of "java.exe".  Mine was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\"

The JarDir needs to have the path to the "antlr-3.3.jar" file.  I set the path from your error message above.